# sign_up using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio

Hey i have created a sign_up method to insert into my database 'newSchool' using proc 'new_student' but whenever i try it in my browser gives me SqlException error at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

here is the code :

```
protected void sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("new_student", conn);
    cmd.CommandText = "EXEC new_student @user , @name , @pass , @date , SELECT S.ID FROM Schools S where S.name = @school";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", suser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", sname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", spass.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", sdate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@school", sschool.SelectedValue);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    Response.Redirect("localhost:17009/Welcome%20page.aspx");
}
```

that's the error : [image]

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: check the question i printscreened the error

Comment: this doesn't help much without the exception detais. What you could do to fix this quickly is to take the command text and try to run it in sql itself either by taking the command text and executing it as a query or by running an sql profiler to audit the commands that are being run.

Comment: result of select statement is used as parameter to your new_student_user procedure. I think this is all where things went wrong. What was your intention?. Does your procedure accept table value as 5th parameter ?

Comment: But we can't interact with a screenshot. You have to drill into the exception details to get the inner exception.

Comment: Not sure why you all seem to think you need an exception here. Look at the CommandText. It's simply not valid SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to setup the `commandtype = CommandType.StoredProcedure` before setting command text. Then in `commandtext` supply the name of the procedure alone. For any further clarification reffer to the following link:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC new_student @user , @name , @pass , @date , SELECT S.ID FROM Schools S where S.name = @school";
```

That is not valid SQL. As the screenshot says, you have incorrect syntax near the keyword "SELECT." The incorrect syntax starts with the comma after @date. You cannot pass an unquoted SELECT statement as a parameter to a stored proc.